# how to call a javascript function in foreach in mvc3 view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to call a JavaScript function in c# code in asp.net mvc3 view, but don't know how to do this. My code is following

**Javascript Function**

```
function JK(){

   alert("Javascript Function Called From foreach");

  }
```

**C# Foreach**

```
foreach(var item in collection){ //I want to call JavaScript function here on every iterate.  
}
```

Comment: You would be better off using jQuery, assigning your DOM elements with a CSS class and using the jQuery.each.

Answer (score 14):

Well you can use something like this:

```
foreach (var item in collection) {
   <script type="text/javascript">
     JK();
   </script>
}
```

If you need to use foreach inside the javascript code, you should just use . Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @foreach (var item in collection) {
      <text>JK();</text>
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would implement it little bit differently

```
@foreach(var item in collection)
{
    <!-- some html element that will be generated on each loop cycle
    <input type="hidden" class="item"/>
}
```

then with/without help of 3rd party JavaScript libraries

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').each(function () {
        JK();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call JS function on server side only in the views. And it wiil look like

```
@foreach(var item in collection)
{
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
     JK()
  </script>
  ...
}
```

Output html will contain several calls of this js function.

Answer (score -2):

To call a javascript function

```
   //C# Code
@Html.Raw("CallFunction('" + @param + "');");
    //C# code..
```

Now for Javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     CallFunction(param)
     {
       alert(param);
     }
  </script>
```