# Call javascript function from switch case in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Want make call to javascript function from switch case statment in asp.net mvc:

```
@select Case imageExistOrNot(this)
   Case True
      @<a onclick="showCardImage(this)">Show</a>
   Case False
      @<a>No Image</a>
End Select
```

And have test JS method:

```
function imageExistOrNot()  
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are calling a client method named `showCardImage` but the only js method you have in your question is named `imageExistOrNot`. Also you pass in 1 parameter but the method defined takes 0 parameters.... Is there something you are not showing or included by mistake??

Comment: I have no knowledge of VB.NET, but I have the feeling your `@select Case` is executed on server-side. If that's the case, then what you are asking is not possible and does not make sense at all.

Comment: @Igor see `@select Case imageExistOrNot`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - ah. Ok, then its simple, you cant call client side script during server side rendering of the view.

Comment: I need to call controller method that return true/false, instead of js function?

Comment: This [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789651/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-in-foreach-in-mvc3-view) shows how to call js functions from the view.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC => runs at server
Javascript => runs at client, once server finished processing

You are expecting the server to know the result of a client function, which is not possible.

Comment: So how can i determine if image exist ot not? with controller method?

Comment: @BallonUra You need to perform the validation with Javascript and then call the server using AJAX (for example)

Comment: @BallonUra How are you using JS to determine if the image exists or not?  Surely that's a server-side function anyway?